# AWS Step Function how to imitate StringStartsWith condition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I need to invoke different lambda depends on first letter of payload field. There is no appropriate [Choice Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html#amazon-states-language-choice-state-rules). Is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're matching on the value of the field, it's possible to use the `StringMatches` operator.

For instance, this should check $.some_field value and move to state `Goto_A`,`Goto_B`,`Goto_C` or if none match `Goto_Error`.

```yaml
States:
  Choice_FirstLetterOfSomeField:
    Type: Choice
    Choices:
      - Variable: $.some_field
        StringMatches: 'a*'
        Next: Goto_A
      - Variable: $.some_field
        StringMatches: 'b*'
        Next: Goto_B
      - Variable: $.some_field
        StringMatches: 'c*'
        Next: Goto_C
    Default: Goto_Error
```

Comment: That's correct. There was no such rule at that time. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Step Functions doesn't support a string pattern matching comparison operator. A workaround is to use a Lambda function with that does this comparison and check the result of the comparison using a Choice state.